# How to prevent the fill command in MATLAB from creating boxes without "corners"

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am currently using the fill command in MATLAB to create a graph of boxes that were created using the 'fill' command (the actual code is based off [this StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008705/how-to-create-a-shaded-error-bar-box-for-a-scatterplot-in-r-or-matlab).

My issue is that the boxes that I create do not have "corners." I am attaching a PNG that illustrates the issue. Note that you have to look a little carefully since the image was heavily rendered, though in this example my arrows also look weird since they don't have edges either)[image]

I am wondering if anyone has an idea of what might be going wrong? The boxes appear this way immediately after I use the fill command, which has the following structure:

```
fill(X,Y,MyFaceColor,'FaceAlpha',0.5,'EdgeColor', MyEdgeColor,'LineStyle','','LineWidth',box_line_width,'EdgeAlpha',1)
```

Comment: Interesting Q. An additional oddity: I was playing around with `rectangle` as an answer to this, which works but doesn't allow transparency. However, if you use a `fill` or a `patch` **after** using a rectangle, the rectangle corners (which were correct) go funny!

Comment: Ah! The reason is the renderer. Using a transparent graphics object sets the renderer to `opengl`. This can be overridden by using `set(gcf,'renderer','painters');` - this will help your corners (they're still not great), but your transparency does not work. It seems to be a bug of the opengl renderer, I tried playing around with it and I couldn't find a simple workaround, short of drawing lines manuall. Maybe there is a known way to do this?

Comment: Ahh the 'opengl' vs. 'painters' dilemna. I ran into this earlier when I was trying to export the picture as a PDF. There's not much you can do to work around it unfortunately. Thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `fill` appears to leave space for corner markers if they are not explicitly defined. Hence, calling `fill` with the `marker` property will solve your problem. However, since markers and linewidths seem to work on different scales, you will have to play around with the marker size to get smooth edges.

Example:

```
fill(X,Y,'r','FaceAlpha',0.5,'EdgeColor', 'k',...
    'LineWidth', 5,'EdgeAlpha',1 , 'marker', '.', 'markersize', 15)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Do you know if the same idea applies to the arrows?

Comment: @BerkU. If you created them with `fill`, yes.

Comment: Nice hack. +1. This is why vector graphics is hard and even harder in Matlab. Real vector graphics programs (Adobe Illustrator and that ilk) allow one to change a line's "end cap" style and alignment properties. Even CSS's canvas has this capability when drawing vectors. I don't know if the [new HG2](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/hg2-update/) will resolve this, but I consider it a bug worthy of [filing](http://www.mathworks.com/support/service_requests/contact_support.do) with The MathWorks.

Comment: @horchler: Actually, Mathworks does not consider this a bug, but instead advertises it as a feature: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/visualize/specifying-patch-coloring.html#brbl7d6

Comment: @H.Muster: Nice article! I didn't mean that your idea of putting markers at the corners is a bug. It's nice that we have that and it kind of serves as a workaround. Rather, I meant that one cannot simply adjust the end cap style and must resort to fiddly schemes in order to obtain boxes with arbitrary line thicknesses.